# How to exclude some options from React Select options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have around 50 options to be shown in the react select options. But I want to exclude some of the options with logic to already posted values.
The purpose is, that we have a form where we add values from the drop-down list. if one item is been added then that should not have to be shown in the dropdown list.

refactored code:

```
export default function App() {
  const choices = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: "Container empty to shipper"
    },
    {
      value: 1,
      label: "Container pickup at shipper"
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: "Container arrival at first POL (Gate in)"
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      label: "Container loaded at first POL"
    }
  ];

  const postedList = [
    "Container empty to shipper",
    "Container pickup at shipper"
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Select Box</h1>
      <Select
        isClearable={false}
        // here the choices should be 2 eliminating the other 2 whose labels are matching to postedlist 
        options={choices}
        defaultValue={choices[0]}
        onChange={(choice) => console.log(choice.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently, it's rendering all 4 choices available but I want to return only 2 of them whose labels are not matching to `postedlist`

I also have created [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cherry-8xkwgs?file=/src/App.js). If you want to see it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to filter out already posted items. Then use the `filteredList` as input to the `Select` component as below.

```
  const filteredList = choices.filter(({ label }) =>
    !postedList.includes(label)
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Select Box</h1>
      <Select
        isClearable={false}
        options={filteredList}
        defaultValue={filteredList[0]}
        onChange={(choice) => console.log(choice.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Edit happy-wave-yktw2j]

Comment: @atropa belladona, check this out !!

Comment: Thats not working as should be , Lets say if I removed once item from postedList then there should 3 options to be rendered as options .,

Comment: Please check this issue again , i need to exclude the items from choices comparing with postedList

Comment: @atropabelladona you should add "!"(not) before postedList.includes to exclude labels that are "not" matching.

Comment: I have missed `!`, in front of includes. Now updated the answer! Please check !

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically `filter` items and exclude them with the `includes` method.

```js
    <Select
    options = {choices.filter((choice) => !postedList.includes(choice.label))}
    ...
    />
```